# Simple Jasmine test failing

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

Below is an angularJS Factory

```
angular.module('employer').factory('emp', function($rootScope, $ionicPopup, $state, $window){

var pop = {}; 

pop.integrate = function(){
       return 123;
    };
});
```

Following are Jasmine tests I have tried,

1)

```
it('integration', function(){
              expect(pop.integrate).toEqual(123);
              });
```

This gives me an error - `Expected undefined to equal 123.`

2)

```
it('integration', function(){
              spyOn(pop, 'integrate');
              pop.integrate();
              expect(pop.integrate).toHaveBeenCalled();
              expect(pop.integrate).toEqual(123);
              });
```

This gives me an error - `pop.integrate()` is not a function.